# Get Registry Value name

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I am trying to get the name of reg value and then delete it. This registry is String value and its name is different on almost machines however there is common thing in name is "Excompass.exe"
I am using this query to get the registry key:-

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" |findstr /i "Encompass.exe"
```

It is showing result like following:-

```
C:\SmartClientCache\Apps\Ellie Mae\Encompass\Encompass.exe    REG_SZ   $ IgnoreFreeLibrary<AcroRd32.dll>
```

Problem is, I just need a name "C:\SmartClientCache\Apps\Ellie Mae\Encompass\Encompass.exe"  but I am unable to extract it.

How we can get this registry value name ?

I can easily do this with PowerShell but I need this in CMD.

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the result of just the req query.

Comment: If you can do it in PowerShell why can't you just run that from cmd ?  `Powershell .....` where .... is the powershell command??

Comment: @Mr R. The result comes like following:-

 "C:\SmartClientCache\Apps\Ellie Mae\Encompass\Encompass.exe    REG_SZ   $ IgnoreFreeLibrary<AcroRd32.dll>"

I am using RMM. Powershell command doesnt work on HKCU Reg. So I need to run cmd command.

Answer (score 0):

#### How we can get this registry value name?

Something like the following should work <sup>(not tested)</sup>:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 %%i in (`reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" |findstr /i "Encompass.exe"`) do (
  echo %%i
  rem do something with %%i
  )
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.